# java, how to convert Epoch time to day of weeks only

Tags: java, time, epoch

For example i have datevalue=1479709790; which is in Epoch 
and i want to convert this Epoch time to only day of week like Sunday, Monday or Tuesday only. the below will get day oneday above like it get monday before sunday.

```
public String getDay(long day){
    this.day=day;
    String dayOfWeeks;
    long time=day*1000l;

    int days = (int)((time/(1000*60*60*24))%7);

   switch (days){
       case 1:
           dayOfWeeks = "Sun";
           break;
       case 2:
           dayOfWeeks="Mon";
           break;
       case 3:
           dayOfWeeks = "Tue";
           break;
       case 4:
           dayOfWeeks="Wed";
           break;
       case 5:
           dayOfWeeks = "Thru";
           break;
       case 6:
           dayOfWeeks="Frid";
           break;
       case 7:
           dayOfWeeks = "Sat";
           break;
       default:
           dayOfWeeks="Sat";
   }

    return dayOfWeeks;
}
```

Comment: What epoch is that in, what scale, what result should you get, what result do you get, what have you tried?

Comment: `Instant.ofEpochMilli(1479709790L * 1000L)` says your date is `2016-11-21T06:29:50Z`. What time zone do you want to get the day-of-week in? In time zone `Australia/Sydney` that would be `MONDAY`, but in time zone `America/Anchorage` that would be `SUNDAY`.

Comment: When using `% 7`, the result will be a number between 0 and 6, inclusive, so why does your `switch` statement have a `case 7`? And if day names are shifted one, you obviously built the `switch` wrong, so why not just move the names to the right `case`?

Comment: @Andreas `Instant.ofEpochSecond(1479709790L)`...

Comment: @assylias DOH! Of course. Guess I'm still a bit stuck on the old java Date logic, huh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you don't account for timezones (i.e. assume everything is UTC), it could be as simple as:

```
public static DayOfWeek getDayOfWeek(long epochSecond) {
  return Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).getDayOfWeek();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Above methods( `ofEpochSecond(epochSecond).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` ) is not working for  API lower than 26 !
so you can use below code

```
   public static String getdayOfWeek(long epochinSecond) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(epochinSecond * 1000l);
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    int i = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    String dayOfWeek;
    switch (i) {
        case 1:
            dayOfWeek = "Sunday";
            break;
        case 2:
            dayOfWeek = "Monday";
            break;
        case 3:
            dayOfWeek = "Tuesady";
            break;
        case 4:
            dayOfWeek = "Wednesday";
            break;
        case 5:
            dayOfWeek = "Thursday";
            break;
        case 6:
            dayOfWeek = "Friday";
            break;
        case 7:
            dayOfWeek = "Saturday";
            break;
        default:
            dayOfWeek = null;

    }
    return dayOfWeek;

}
```